# Cloudera insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, memory, cloudera

I try to connect to my public dns instance to cloudera on port 7180

I get 'Unable to connect' message in my webbrowser.

I use EC2 AWS + RedHat7 + Cloudera 5

When I start Cloudera Server I get message:

```
root@ip-100-10-10-10 sysconfig]#  service cloudera-scm-server start 
Starting cloudera-scm-server (via systemctl):              [  OK  ]
```

When I curl I get:

```
[root@ip-100-10-10-10 sysconfig]# curl -i -u ‘admin:admin’ http://localhost:7180/api/v1/tools/echo
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:7180; Connection refused
```

this is the log file for cloudera server with command `sudo ls -l /var/log/cloudera-scm-server`

```
[root@ip-172-31-45-90 sysconfig]# $sudo cat /var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.out 
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000787295000, 155291648, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 155291648 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid2370.log
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Regarding the error, you haven't told us what the available memory resources of the EC2 instance are

Comment: I do not know how to check it yet ... i set it up 1st time ...

Comment: You had to pick a [instance type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) when you started EC2... For what it's worth, I don't think you can run Cloudera Manager on anything less 8GB of memory

Comment: yes, I have chosen the basic one, the one for free ...

Comment: Yeah, Cloudera Manager won't run on the free edition. Doesn't have enough memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use EC2 AWS ... I have chosen the basic one, the one for free

Read the [Cloudera Manager installation guide](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/manager/5-1-x/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cm5ig_cm_requirements.html)

> **RAM** - 4 GB is appropriate for most cases, and is required when using
>   Oracle databases. 2 GB may be sufficient for non-Oracle deployments
>   involving fewer than 100 hosts. However, if you want to run the
>   Cloudera Manager Server on a machine with 2 GB of RAM, you must tune
>   down its maximum heap size (by modifying -Xmx in
>   /etc/default/cloudera-scm-server). Otherwise the kernel may kill the
>   Server for consuming too much RAM

I would go further and say that is the recommended **free space** to have, so 6 or 8GB would be my recommendation if you plan on running all the services. The t2.micro, or t2.nano, or whatever instance type you have doesn't have that much memory.